# JavaScript Screen Capture separate DOM elements

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have this code below that contains 3 separated divs i'm currently able to capture and download the yellow div in a png image. But what i'm trying to accomplish is to capture the yellow and black into a single image and download it.

Is this function possible with the library i'm using or is there a better way to do it? Any help / suggestion would be greatly appreciated thanks.

```js
function sendData() {
  html2canvas(document.getElementById('capture')).then(function(canvas) {
    $('#test').attr('href', canvas.toDataURL('image/png'));
    $('#test').attr('download', 'Test.png');
    $('#test')[0].click();
  });
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <link rel="shortcut icon" href="//#" />
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://html2canvas.hertzen.com/dist/html2canvas.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://html2canvas.hertzen.com/dist/html2canvas.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="capture" style="padding: 10px; background: #f5da55">
    <h4 style="color: #000; ">Helloo world!</h4>
  </div>

  <div style="padding: 10px; background: pink">
    <h4 style="color: #000; ">Helloo world!</h4>
  </div>

  <div style="padding: 10px; background: black">
    <h4 style="color: white; ">Helloo world!</h4>
  </div>
  <div id="match-button" onclick="sendData();">capture</div>
  <a id="test" href="#"></a>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: What becomes the pink one then? Is it converted to white? Filled with transparent pixels? Simply removed (as in no gap at all)? Anyway, an easy solution is to manipulate your css just before you call h2c, and then restore it after.

Comment: @Kaiido What do you mean by manipulate my css?

Comment: You temporarily modify your document to what you want it to be rendered, and then you restore it once h2c has done its job. https://jsfiddle.net/trowq37z/

Comment: @Kaiido Hmm yeah it works but i tried adding in back my download function but it is suddenly not working.

Comment: @Kaiido Is it possible to make it not show the modified divs and just download it?